# How can I change int and boolean at main.py from events.py

Tags: python

Python newbie here needing some help! my problemo is as follows:

So let's say I have booleans (b_lesscookies and b_morecookies) and int (Cookiecount) in main.py

```
import events
bring_events = events.c_cookiethings()

Cookiecount = 4

b_lesscookies = True
b_morecookies = False

done = False
while not done:
    if b_lesscookies == True:
        bring_events.f_lesscookies()
    elif b_morecookies == True:
        bring_events.f_morecookies()
```

Then I have events.py where something should happen to Cookiecount and b_lesscookies so that loop in main.py doesn't keep just lowering Cookiecount:

```
class c_cookiethings():

    def f_lesscookies(self):
        Cookiecount -= 1
        b_lesscookies = False 

    def f_morecookies(self):
        Cookiecount += 1
```

How can I get **main.py** and **events.py** communicate changes in **Cookiecount**, **b_lesscookies** and **b_morecookies** between each other? like here, to make b_lesscookies = False so that loop in main.py doesn't just keep lowering Cookiecount too much?

I've tried few things, but none of them work. Tried to google my problem, but can't find exactly same problem. Sorry if my problem is common problem and I keep asking same question many other Python newbies have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you're trying to do is set a global variable. search for "global variable python". in general, i think globals are a bad idea, but alas...

Comment: You could store the states in a separate file, say *datastore.txt*. You would need to read and write to the file from each of your scripts. In principle this will work. If you are interested in a higher level of this, check out something like SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many ways to deal with this issue is to make `b_lesscookies`,
`b_morecookies` and `Cookiecount` [class variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). It would be something like:

```
class c_cookiethings():         
    b_lesscookies = True
    b_morecookies = False
    Cookiecount = 4

    def f_lesscookies(self):
        self.Cookiecount -= 1
        self.b_lesscookies = False 

    def f_morecookies(self):
        self.Cookiecount += 1
```

and:

```
import events
bring_events = events.c_cookiethings()

done = False
while not done:
    if c_cookiethings.b_lesscookies == True:
        bring_events.f_lesscookies()
    elif c_cookiethings.b_morecookies == True:
        bring_events.f_morecookies()
```

As it was mention in the comments, You could also use the global variables, but it's usually considered a bad practice. Another solution is to store values that You want to reach from different scripts in a file or a database but it's not practical for such a little amount of data. I think that using class variables is the cleanest solution in this case. Also please read about the difference between the [instance and class variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), because probably Your code could be redesigned to use instance variables, which would be even cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I see :) I think this is the solution to my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @EsaT.H. Cheers! I would recommend You to read some good tutorial on classes though, because probably Your code could be designed differently and You wouldn't encounter such issue.